# how to have a category blog and category list on the same page in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to make it so that I can have a category blog that displays three articles, and one of those articles be a category list that will list some other recent new articles on my site. Is there any way of doing this in Core joomla or do I need a plugin?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could use loadmodule to load a latest news or other module set to display the categories you want into one of the articles in your blog. Alternatively you could have an alternate layout that renders that module would need for an article.